Breaking a safe in underwear
In the beginning of the movie a pair of travelers are walking through woody terrain covered in deep snow, well dressed for cold winter. They reach some sort of bunker and go inside. There it turns out they are a man and a woman, and that the red-hued interior is unbearably warm. They are forced to remove all their clothing except for the underwear. The woman asks why he haven't warned her about the heat, and the man replied that she wouldn't have believed him. They are there to break a safe. The safe has a keypad with matrix with a lot of keys, maybe even 10x10=100 keys. One of them presses some of the keys in appropriate sequence and appropriate pattern, and the pressed keys are lit up.
This happens in the first 10 minutes, or so. It's probably a spy thriller from the late seventies.
EDIT: user Anderson reminded me of one more fact. After removing almost all their clothes  they poured a liquid (could be a chilled champagne) on their bodies to better manage the heat. Anderson also mentions some special fuel pellets causing all the heat, and it could be true, but I have no memory of that detail.

This kind of puts me in mind of Spies Like Us, trying to see if any of the scenes you mention agree with the film plot

I know the comedy with Chevy Chase and Dan Aykroyd. This was no comedy, and there was one man and one woman. The woman maybe betrayed the man later in the film, but maybe I remembered that bit wrong.

Ok, I'll stop searching ;)

Sounds vaguely familiar and Bond-like. Do you remember what the man and woman looked like, perhaps?

Not really. They appeared good looking, but I was too young to recognize them. I mentioned the film being a spy thriller, but the two of them could have been just sophisticated thieves.

I vaguely recall a similar movie. Did the plot involve a heist to steal something. And the heat was caused by thiefs by tempering with heating. It had something to do that alarms do not work when to hot.

That would be Sneakers (1992) with Robert Redford. I saw my movie when I was very young, so late 70's are most likely the time when it was made. BTW, the point of heating in Sneakers is to heat the air to body temperature, so that sensors can't tell the difference. Sensors still worked but couldn't detect the difference in temperature.

@Dialecticus You should move that to an answer.  I don't remember the scene, but it sounds like the movie.

@Jeff-InventorChromeOS I just described scene from Sneakers to Anderson, but Sneakers is not the answer.

And I think the heat was caused by putting special fuel pellets to furnace. And yes in my memory the interior is red also. And somewhere along the line they are wetting themselves with champagne I think.

It might be Hot Ice, a low budget sexploitation film most famous for being the last film Ed Wood worked on before his death.
You might also be remembering this episode of Get Smart which has Agent 99 and a CIA agent in fur coats entering a bunker that's a red room although there's no stripping or keypad add far as I can see.

While it's not Get Smart I won't rule out Hot Ice. I just can't verify it. Even the subtitles are nowhere to be found.
